# Narrowest bandwidth RF filter

Tags: electrical-engineering

Most of the RF filters have a bandwidth 1 MHz or more. Mobiles have a 200 kHz bandwidth filter. What is the narrowest bandwidth possible for a RF filter?

Comment: *"Most of the RF filters have a bandwidth 1 MHz or more."*  This is complete nonsense.  Since your question is based on a flawed premise, it can't be answered.

Answer (score 1):

It ***REALLY*** isn't true to say "most RF filters have a bandwidth of 1 MHz or higher".

Theoretically, there is no limit. You could design a multi-order bandpass filter with very high selectivity, such that it 'rejects' all other frequencies. In actually fact, it will have a gradual 'roll off' either side of the designed passband frequency, which will attenuate any frequencies which aren't in the passbad. Frequencies below which the gain is -3 dB, are said to be 'cut-off'.

All of this is written about in frequency design textbooks.

For example, one such filter topology exists, Bessel (4th order):
[image: filter topology]

That filter has a frequency response that looks like:

[image]

You can see that this is a fairly selective filter. The passband region is only 190 Hz wide... Filters which are highly selective are said to have a very high Q factor.

$$Q=\frac{f_c}{\Delta f}$$

where, $\Delta f$ is the bandwidth (190 Hz) and $f_c$ is the cut-off frequency, 10 kHz.